# Iterate rows of a column for colon in a dataframe and if exists add new column with True

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the shape `(2556, 15)`. I want to add a new column `Check` with the boolean value of the condition that the corresponding column `B` of same row should have a colon. I have tried the following code.

```
for each in df['B']:
    check = df['B'].to_string().__contains__(':')
    if check:
        df['Check'] = check
```

It is adding `True` to all rows of the data frame

Comment: `df['Check'] = df['B'].str.contians(':')`

Comment: df['Check'] = df['column B'].str.contains(':')

Comment: Notice that your `each` variable isn't actually being _used_ inside the loop. That could be a hint that its not doing what you intend. In any case, you should avoid loops like this in Pandas.

Comment: Guys, I'd advise you to stop answering questions in the comments, especially @Zero

Answer (score 0):

Another way `replace`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'B':['In:d','Chn:','SG','U:S:'],'a':[5,6,3,4]})
m=df.B.replace({":":True},regex=True)
df['Check']=m[m==True]

df
Out[1081]: 
      B  a Check
0  In:d  5  True
1  Chn:  6  True
2    SG  3   NaN
3  U:S:  4  True
```